# Get unique records where column type is JSONB

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a complicated Postgres query I'm trying to make, mainly because my columns / data is in the JSONB type.

I need to get all records

- where `Auth.status` is `valid`
- `UserId` is `1`
- Excluding duplicates on `Details.reference.card.number`

Here's my table:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|         Auth          |                   Details                   | UserId |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "4444"}}} |      1 |
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "3321"}}} |      1 |
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "4444"}}} |      1 |
| {"status": "Invalid"} | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "3331"}}} |      1 |
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "4444"}}} |      1 |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
```

This query above should return:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|         Auth          |                   Details                   | UserId |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "4444"}}} |      1 |
| {"status": "valid"}   | {"reference": {"card": {"number": "3321"}}} |      1 |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------+
```

What I have so far.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE "Auth" @> '{"status": "valid"}'
AND "UserId" = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH sample_table AS (
    SELECT 
        "userId",
        p."Auth"->>'status' as "authStatus",
        p."Detail"->'"reference"'->'card'->>'number' as "referenceCardNumber",
    FROM my_table p
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("referenceCardNumber") "referenceCardNumber", *
FROM sample_table
WHERE "authStatus" = 'valid'
AND "userId" = 1
```